# GitHub - Separating content into "folders"

Tags: github

I would like to create "Folders" according to the content, for example "Javascript Folder" or "Nodejs Folder" and on my GitHub homepage.

Instead of showing all projects, only the "folders" could appear, so the visitor to my profile on GitHub would choose the "folder" they like the most to see its content.

Is there this possibility?

Comment: You could put something like that in your [profile README](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme), otherwise no.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can pin *repositories* to your profile. You could make a profile README like jonrsharpe mentioned, and include links to your repository tab based on filters for the "folders" you want to create. For example: here's a link to all of my "*Python repositories containing the word: Dataset*": https://github.com/hayesall?tab=repositories&q=dataset&language=python If you choose tags for JavaScript, NodeJS, etc. that could likely be achieved by tweaking the search parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside [README profile](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme) (that you must maintain, possibly through  a [GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) like [varunsridharan/action-dynamic-readme](https://github.com/varunsridharan/action-dynamic-readme)), you also have:

[GitHub topics](https://github.com/topics), which help classifying your repositories.

You can see an example in the [Microsoft GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft), from where you can easily access to:

- [ML (machine-learning) repositories](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Amachine-learning%20org%3Amicrosoft%20fork%3Atrue)
- [Azure repositories](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Aazure%20org%3Amicrosoft%20fork%3Atrue)
  è ... and so on